# Wav to mp3 bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I can't figure out why the script isn't working,
I don't get any syntax error,
It just does nothing and delete the files

```
#!/bin/bash
recorddir="${1:-/var/spool/asterisk/mp3/}"
cd $recorddir;
for file in *.wav; do
mp3=$(basename "$file" .wav).mp3;
lame V3 "$file" "$mp3";
mv "$mp3" /var/spool/asterisk/rec;
rm -f "$file";
done
```

Comment: change the shebang to "#!/bin/bash -x" and look at the output...

Comment: Or `set -x`, and perhaps `set -e`. And some verbosity flags, e.g. `lame --verbose`, `mv -v`.

Comment: I'm getting "lame: excess arg" followed with the file name, and then followed an "mv: cannot stat" filename.mp3 : no such file or directory. I'm guessing that this happens due to the fact that the lame fails, so no mp3 file created

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `-` in front of `V3` for sure. Otherwise, this is just a very messy script. If there's something more that doesn't work:

- add proper indentation
- strip unnecessary semicolons (they're not needed at the end of the lines - only before `do` in this script)
- set the options that make this script abort on failures and undefined vars: `set -eu`
- quote all variables (most are already ok, but $recorddir isn't)

Comment: `for file in *.wav` does not fail with spaces in filenames. Semicolons are stylistic and don't belong in your list. Both `-e` and `-u` are frowned upon (for good reason) in many circles.

Comment: You're right, my bad. (about the spaces handling) I disagree about -eu in this case. If you know why they're frowned upon, you can choose - if you fail to debug a script as simple as this one, you better use it everywhere, or you'll end up asking really trivial stuff on stackoverflow.

Comment: I can't belive all I was missing was that - in from of V3... LOL, thank you very much

Comment: I'd also recommand use of "&&" to only do commands if the previous worked ( exemple: `cd /correct_dir && { the rest ; } || { echo "couldn't cd into /correct_dir" ; exit 1 ; }` )

Comment: I use `-e` and `-u` much of the time myself, my point was that in a list like yours they seemed to strong (and without listing any of the caveats/issues) you don't give someone the ability to decide correctly. (Not to mention that neither of them would have helped here in the slightest.)